# Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to connect to sql server using vb.net but I got this error:

> *Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.*

this is the cod source:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim connection As SqlConnection()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            connection = New SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog=tp2_ado; integrated security = sspi")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message())
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why the parenthesis in SqlConnection() ?

Comment: I was doing c# and I just started vb.net

Comment: They wouldn't be required in C# either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim connection As SqlConnection ' this should not be an array !
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            connection = New SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog=tp2_ado; integrated security = sspi")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message())
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```